# Smarty: How to read a {$var} stored in the database?

Tags: php, codeigniter, smarty

I use codeigniter with smarty.

I have a variable stored in the db called `$serverName`. I want to expand it to its actual value `"Pedrosite"`. But when the page is loaded, it displays exactly `{$serverName}` and not the value.

So I found this solution on stackoverflow, using smarty's fetch function:

`$data['content']` contains the text from the database.

```
$data['content'] = $this->CI->smarty->fetch('string:'.$data['content']);
```

With that, I can display the smarty vars, like: `{$smarty.const.FCPATH}`

But none of my custom `$vars` while they can be shown in a regular template (`.tpl`).

So I found this workaround that looks very hacky to me:

```
$this->CI->smarty->assign('serverName', $this->CI->config->item('server_name'));
```

I can put this in one of my `__construct` function and then it will affect the whole site, and then it loads properly. But I'm not sure it's the right way to proceed at all.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your question, but, if you have your variable `$serverName` and it content `"Pedrosite"` you can display it like that :

```
$this->smarty->assign('serverName' , $serverName);
$this->smarty->view('/modules/xxxxxx');
```

And display it in your .html file for example :

```
<p>{$serverName}</p>
```

Comment: my question is more about the fact that the code i'm using (not made by me, i'm not really a php dev) doesn't use once `$this->smarty->assign` to define variables, it's all done in php/codeigniter for each variable, so I must be doing something wrong here

Comment: Weird, I use also CodeIgniter/php/Smarty and I always use assign

Comment: well I tried to define another php variable like this $newVar = $serverName and then it said the var is not defined. Seems like I should have everything defined with smarty assign (if it were coded correctly lol)

Comment: ok so the problem i see now with my smarty->fetch, is that stuff like `pattern="[a-zA-Z]{2,15}"` is now causing a big error `'Syntax Error in template` even if I put {literal} tags around it.

Ok I get it, it's because there is a custom Smarty Class