# CodeIgniter/Smarty: How to read {$var} from database?

Tags: php, codeigniter, smarty

I use codeigniter with smarty.

I have this smarty class: https://hastebin.com/milulomido.xml

It gets the job done but it doesn't expand a smarty tag `{$my_tag}` into its actual value **if that tag is stored in the database**. In that case, it will just print `{$my_tag}` literally.

Example of how stuff is taken from the DB:

```
    /**
     * Get the selected page from the database
     * @param String $page
     * @return Array
     */
    public function getPage($page)
    {
        $this->db->select('*')->from('pages')->where('identifier', $page);
        $query = $this->db->get();

        if($query->num_rows() > 0)
        {
            $result = $query->result_array();

            return $result[0];
        }

        return null;
    }
```

I think I need to edit that Smarty class (first link) to fix my issue but don't know how. I have some ideas but they sound hacky (like analyse everything in `$data` and extract the smarty tags found, then assign them as Smarty variables, or fetch a second time the content but it is horrible and introduces bugs).

Comment: instead of a link, could you please edit your post adding a code example (shortest possible) which shows your problem `How to read {$var} from database?`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Smarty: How to read a {$var} stored in the database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55524492/smarty-how-to-read-a-var-stored-in-the-database)